# With WP CLI, wp config create generates error

Tags: mamp, wp-cli

I am using WP CLI to download and install WordPress using MAMP. I run into this error however when trying `wp config create`

```
env: mysql: No such file or directory
```

Couldn't find anything that addressed this error on developer.wordpress and other searches. I could edit the file manually of course, but that would spoil all the fun. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't connect to your database there are a [few possibilities](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/common-issues/#error-cant-connect-to-the-database). One of them is, that you're using MAMP, like in your and my case, but WP-CLI is not using the MAMP PHP binary. You can check that by running

```
wp --info
```

To specify the MAMP PHP binary you'll need to modify your `PATH` enviroment variable. You have to add

```
PHP_VERSION=$(ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1)
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${PHP_VERSION}/bin:$PATH
```

to your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zsh_profile`

If you want to use a specific PHP Version (eg. 5.5.26) just use

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.26/bin:$PATH
```

After saving the file run:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and

```
wp --info
```

to check your changes.

For further reading check the WP-CLI Handbook for [using a custom PHP binary](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/installing/#using-a-custom-php-binary)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you add more details? Your answer was flagged for its length and content.